# Do Shannon entropy and majorization preorder measure the same "type of disorder"?

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy, majorization

Given a probability vector $\mathbf p\equiv (p_k)_{k=1}^n$ with $p_k\ge0$ and $\sum_k p_k=1$, Shannon's entropy is defined as $S(\mathbf p)\equiv -\sum_k p_k \log p_k$.

On the other hand, given two probability vectors $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$, we say that [$\mathbf q$ *is majorized by* $\mathbf p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization), and write $\mathbf q\preceq\mathbf p$, if the sum of the $j$ largest elements of $\mathbf q$ is smaller than the sum of the $j$ largest elements of $\mathbf p$, for all $j$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^j q_j^\downarrow \le \sum_{k=1}^j p_j^\downarrow, \quad \forall j=1,...,n.$$

Both of these quantities can be understood as quantifying how "*disordered*" a probability vector is, albeit obviously in different ways: the entropy assigns a number of each probability distribution, while majorization is a preorder in the set of probability distributions.
Intuitively, $\mathbf p$ is "more disordered" than $\mathbf q$ when $S(\mathbf p)\ge S(\mathbf q)$ or $\mathbf p\preceq \mathbf q$.

It is known that $S$ is *Schur-concave*, *i.e.* that $\mathbf p\preceq\mathbf q$ implies $S(\mathbf p)\ge S(\mathbf q)$.

We also know that there are examples of $\mathbf p,\mathbf q$ which are not comparable via majorization but are such that $S(\mathbf p)\le S(\mathbf q)$. For example, $\mathbf p=(0.5,0.5,0)$ and $\mathbf q=(0.6,0.3,0.1)$.

Is there any intuition as to the different types of "*disorder*" quantified by entropy and majorization? Is either "superior" than the other for some applications?

Moreover, does $S(\mathbf p)\ge S(\mathbf q)$ imply $\mathbf p\preceq \mathbf q$ if we assume that $\mathbf q$ and $\mathbf p$ are comparable?

Comment: From your wiki link: $p \prec q$ if and only if for each convex function $h: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ it holds that $\sum_j h(p_j) \leq \sum_j h(q_j)$. If the last implication in your question is true, then this would mean that on some subset of the simplex one could replace the condition by just checking one particular convex function - which sounds a bit too strong, although I do not have a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my comment above I got the logic wrong, indeed at least it is true that $S(p) > S(q)$ and $p,q$ comparable imply $p \prec q$.

To see this, we use [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization)
$$p \prec q \iff  \sum_i h(p_i) \leq \sum_i h(q_i)$$

for all convex $ h: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$, since $p_i,q_i \geq 0 \ \forall i$.

Now for a fixed $p$ this means that the set of probability vectors that are comparable to it can be described as

$$C_p =\{ q \in \Delta_n| q \prec p \lor p \prec q\}\\
 =  \left\{ q \in \Delta_n| \left(\sum_i h(p_i) \geq \sum_i h(q_i) \, \forall \ h \ \text{convex}\right)\right\} \cup \left\{q \in \Delta_n| \left(\sum_i h(p_i) \leq  \sum_i h(q_i) \, \forall \ h \ \text{convex}\right)\right\}  .$$

Since we know already one convex function ($ x \mapsto - x\ln x$) for which the requirement of the first set does not hold, $q$ has to be in the second set and thus $p \prec q$.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Better if you explian what does $ \Delta_n$ mean.